# jQuery UI spinner string format

Tags: jquery, string, jquery-ui, format, jquery-ui-spinner

this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xHzMw/1/) shows hours/minutes/seconds spinners
and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6466243/559465) offers a function to pad integers with zeros

```
function pad (str, max) {
  str = str.toString();
  return str.length < max ? pad("0" + str, max) : str;
}
```

as simple as the thought of merging those two might seem like it's not working.
the goal I'm aiming for with this is to have the spinner to spin in 2 digit format format.
I've looked into spinners I didn't find any built-in helpers for this issue

here's [the updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eng_katia/xHzMw/62/)
any pointers about the code or the sipnners options is appreciated

thanks for responding guys :>
even though `numberFormat` answer is correct I'd like to point out that it won't work without the `globalize.js` included as noted is [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14346441/559465) of this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345574/jquery-ui-spinner-for-minutes)^^ sorry about duplicating
one more thing, the `globalize.js` original file isn't available for some reason but the kind answer-er appended the code in his fiddle so don't bother searching & get it from there
thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [numberFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/spinner/#option-numberFormat%20numberFormat) option:

```
$('#seconds').spinner({ numberFormat: "d2" });
$('#minutes').spinner({ numberFormat: "d2" });
```

Answer (score 1):

Created a fiddle. Simply appending zero .. based on value. Hope this helps. :)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6t9bS/14/)

```
$( ".spinner" ).spinner({ 
    min: 1,
    max: 999,
    stop: function() {
        if($(this).val() <10)
        $(this).siblings('.spinner-text').val('0'+$(this).val());
        else
        $(this).siblings('.spinner-text').val($(this).val());
    }
 }).parent().append('<input class="spinner-text">');


$('.spinner-text').change(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.spinner').val(($(this).val()));
});
```